# Property 'Navigator' doesn't exist Error: React Native app

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Whenever I run my app through snack I keep getting this error: React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: Navigator. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values like 'Navigator' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

I tried looking on the web for fixes and tried reinstalling some packages but nothing would work.

The code related to the error is here:

```
export default function App() { 

  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      if (image != null){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', {
      uri: image,
      name: 'image.jpg',
      type: 'image/jpeg',
    });

    fetch('http://192.168.1.75:8000/classify', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        Navigator.navigate('Detail', { disease: data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

    
  }
  }, [image, Navigator])
```

I tried to reinstall packages but that didnt work.
I tried running it through my phone but that didnt work either
I tried deleting code bit by bit but would still result in the error

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@shivi0423/moledetect
This is my snack for anyone who wants to see my code

Answer (score 1):

Hey:) The useEffect hook should only include dependencies that are used within the effect itself.
The Navigator variable should not be included in the dependency array because it is a global object and changing it does not cause the component to be re-rendered.

To solve this problem, you can remove Navigator from the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (image != null) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', {
            uri: image,
            name: 'image.jpg',
            type: 'image/jpeg',
    });

    fetch('http://192.168.1.75:8000/classify', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
    })
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((data) => {
       Navigator.navigate('Detail', { disease: data });
   })
   .catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
   });
 }
}, [image]);
```

In the HomeScreen function, instead of navigation={props.navigation} there should be navigation={navigation}.

Change "Navigator.navigate('Detail', { disease: data }) to navigation.navigate('Detail', { disease: data })".

In the "useEffect" function you are missing a dependency in the dependency array. Add "image" to this array.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
import { ApplicationProvider } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import { ListCustomItemShowcase } from './pages/Home';
import CameraIcon from './pages/components/Camera';
import Details from './pages/Details';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import DiseaseDetails from './pages/DiseaseDetails';
import { AppRegistry, Platform } from "react-native";
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in the Expo client or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
if (Platform.OS == "android") {
  registerRootComponent(App);
} else {
  AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <ListCustomItemShowcase navigation={navigation} />
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeContainer() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Detail' component={DiseaseDetails} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (image != null) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image', {
        uri: image,
        name: 'image.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
      });

      fetch('http://192.168.1.75:8000/classify', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          navigation.navigate('Detail', { disease: data });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  }, [image]);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
              let iconName;

              if (route.name === 'Disease') {
                iconName = focused
                  ? 'ios-information-circle'
                  : 'ios-information-circle-outline';
              } else if (route.name === 'Founders') {
                iconName = focused ? 'ios-list' : 'ios-list-outline';
              }

              return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
            },
            tabBarActiveTintColor: '#337cbd',
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
          })}
        >
          <Tab.Screen name="Disease" component={HomeContainer} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Founders" component={Details} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
        <CameraIcon onPress={pickImage} />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ApplicationProvider>
  );
}
```

Try updating @ui-kitten/components to the latest version that supports your version of React Native and Expo.

Updated answer:
Judging by the logs, your project requires a version of @react-navigation/native at least 5.5.1, but it also requires a version of @react-navigation/native at least 6.0.0 for @react-navigation/stack. To resolve this conflict you need to update the @react-navigation/native version in your project to 6.x.x.

Enter the command in the terminal:

```
npm install @react-navigation/native@^6.0.0
```

And

```
npm i
```

To update all dependencies
If an error appears like the one I had at first: "CommandError: It looks like you're trying to use web support but don't have the required dependencies installed.

Please install react-native-web@~0.19.6, react-dom@18.2.0 by running:

npx expo install react-native-web@~0.19.6 react-dom@18.2.0

If you're not using web,
please ensure you remove the "web" string from the platforms array in the project Expo config." Then install the dependencies to support the web platform:

```
npx expo install react-native-web@~0.19.6 react-dom@18.2.0
```

package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.3",
    "@react-navigation/core": "6.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.12",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "5.3.1",
    "expo": "~49.0.18",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.4",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.4.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "10.0.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: This works but after using your changes I get another error saying that: Property 'React' doesn't exist

Comment: If you could also help me with these errors, that would be great!

Comment: Error: "React is not defined" in ReferenceError: React is not defined

Comment: Make sure you have imported React in your file: import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
The "React is not defined" error occurs when a React variable is not defined but is used in code

Comment: @ShivenKhurana My friend, I looked at your code and understood why you are getting the “React is not defined” error. You are using the "Navigator" variable inside the "fetch" function, which is not defined in this context. You need to use the navigation from React Navigation to get to the details screen. I've added an answer.
Check and tell me if everything worke

Comment: unfortunately this may have worked for navigation, but is still producing the error: ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at n.value (@ui-kitten.components:563:1160).

Thanks for all of your help so far!

Comment: The error indicates that there is a problem accessing React within the @ui-kitten/components library. Maybe you should try a different version of ui-kitten? But first check if your version of react-native is compatible with ui-kitten. I’ll try to run your application locally and try to figure out the problem :)

Comment: friend, I ran the application locally and found several dependency version conflicts in the logs. I've updated the answer

Comment: sure. in the answer

Comment: let me know if everything worked or not

Comment: alas the error still shows. I had updated the dependencies like you had stated

Comment: can u upload ur backend to git and if the repository is private then make me a member? I will run it locally, otherwise due to the fact that I can't send a request to the backend, I don't see this error on mine, my git is https://github.com/a1ero

Comment: https://github.com/ShivenKhurana1/MoleDetect

Comment: So, I ran a lot of tests, even ran ur app in debug mode locally, there were no errors on all devices, the app works perfectly. Here is a link to the screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/cTN5EvJ Then I decided to upload ur app to snack.expo.dev and received the same error as urs: "React is not defined". I scoured a bunch of forums about snack.expo.dev and concluded that snack.expo.dev has a different development environment and very often errors occur there. Unfortunately, this cannot be fixed. All that remains is to develop and test on ur local server